# Adminhtml grid display something other than values

Tags: magento-1.9, adminhtml, grid

I'm new to **Adminhtml** and am using it for the first time.

In my `Edit/Form.php` I have a `_prepareForm` function which is working great, here is the code:

```
protected function _prepareForm()
    {  
        $model = Mage::registry('sociable_page');
        $nameValues = [];
        $serviceTitle = [];
        $serviceId = [];
        $service = Mage::getModel('sociable/service')->getCollection();
        foreach($service as $data){
            array_push($serviceTitle, $data->getTitle());
            array_push($serviceId, $data->getServicesId());
        }
        $counter = count($serviceTitle);
        for($i = 0 ; $i < $counter ; $i++){
            $serviceArray[] = array(
                    'value' => $serviceId[$i],
                    'label' => $serviceTitle[$i]
                    );
        }

        $nameValues = array(
                array('value' => 'none', 'label' => Mage::helper('sociable')->__('None')),
                array('value' => 'sociable.product_page', 'label' => Mage::helper('sociable')->__('Inside product page')),
                array('value' => 'sociable.left_top', 'label' => Mage::helper('sociable')->__('Sidebar left top')),
                array('value' => 'sociable.left_bottom', 'label' => Mage::helper('sociable')->__('Sidebar left bottom')),
                array('value' => 'sociable.right_top', 'label' => Mage::helper('sociable')->__('Sidebar right top')),
                array('value' => 'sociable.right_bottom', 'label' => Mage::helper('sociable')->__('Sidebar right bottom')),
                array('value' => 'sociable.content_top', 'label' => Mage::helper('sociable')->__('Content top')),
                array('value' => 'sociable.content_bottom', 'label' => Mage::helper('sociable')->__('Content bottom')),
            );

        $form = new Varien_Data_Form(array(
            'id'        => 'edit_form',
            'action'    => $this->getUrl('*/*/save', array('id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('id'))),
            'method'    => 'post'
        ));

        $fieldset = $form->addFieldset('base_fieldset', array(
            'legend'    => Mage::helper('checkout')->__('Page Information'),
            'class'     => 'fieldset-wide',
        ));

        if ($model->getId()) {
            $fieldset->addField('id', 'hidden', array(
                'name' => 'id',
            ));
        }  

        $fieldset->addField('name', 'select', array(
            'name'      => 'name',
            'label'     => Mage::helper('checkout')->__('Name'),
            'title'     => Mage::helper('checkout')->__('Name'),
            'required'  => true,
            'values'    => $nameValues,
        ));

        $fieldset->addField('services', 'multiselect', array(
            'name'      => 'services',
            'label'     => Mage::helper('checkout')->__('Services'),
            'title'     => Mage::helper('checkout')->__('Services'),
            'required'  => true,
            'values'    => $serviceArray,
        ));

        $form->setValues($model->getData());
        $form->setUseContainer(true);
        $this->setForm($form);

        return parent::_prepareForm();
    }
```

The issue I'm having, is that upon saving the entry to the grid, it will display the VALUES of what was saved. I want to find a way to display the Title instead of the values. I'm thinking this would be done in Grid.php?

Here is my grid.php:

```
protected function _prepareColumns()
    {
        // Add the columns that should appear in the grid
        $this->addColumn('id',
            array(
                'header'=> $this->__('ID'),
                'align' =>'right',
                'width' => '50px',
                'index' => 'id'
            )
        );

        $this->addColumn('name',
            array(
                'header'=> $this->__('Name'),
                'index' => 'name'
            )
        );

        $this->addColumn('services',
            array(
                'header'=> $this->__('Services'),
                'index' => 'services'
                )
        );

        return parent::_prepareColumns();
    }
```

Is there a way to make the grid show something other than the values? For example, in my **"Services"** array, I'd like to display the LABELS in the grid instead of the values.

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is to set the column *type* to *options* in `protected function _prepareColumns()`. For example:

```
$this->addColumn('name', array(
    'header'    => Mage::helper('sociable')->__('Name'),
    'index'     => 'name',
    'type'      => 'options',
    'options'   => array(
        'sociable.product_page' => Mage::helper('sociable')->__('Inside product page')),
        'sociable.left_top' => Mage::helper('sociable')->__('Sidebar left top')),
        'sociable.left_bottom' => Mage::helper('sociable')->__('Sidebar left bottom')),
        'sociable.right_top' => Mage::helper('sociable')->__('Sidebar right top')),
        'sociable.right_bottom' => Mage::helper('sociable')->__('Sidebar right bottom')),
        'sociable.content_top' => Mage::helper('sociable')->__('Content top')),
        'sociable.content_bottom' =>  Mage::helper('sociable')->__('Content bottom'))
    ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your Edit/Form.php file,
its like

```
class {{ your class  }} extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form
{
        protected function _prepareForm()
        {
                $form = new Varien_Data_Form(array(
                "id" => "edit_form",
                "action" => $this->getUrl("*/*/save", array("id" => $this->getRequest()->getParam("id"))),
                "method" => "post",
                "enctype" =>"multipart/form-data",
                )
                );
                $form->setUseContainer(true);
                $this->setForm($form);
                return parent::_prepareForm();
        }
}
```

And In your grid block define column and collection

```
class {{gridclass_Grid}} extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid
     extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid
{
    public function __construct()
    {
            parent::__construct();
            $this->setId("franchisesorderGrid");
            $this->setDefaultSort("franchises_order_id");
            $this->setDefaultDir("DESC");
            $this->setSaveParametersInSession(true);
    }
    protected function _prepareCollection()
    {
        $customerquery = new Zend_Db_Expr("( SELECT entity_id, group_concat(VALUE SEPARATOR ' ') AS franchisseholdername FROM customer_entity_varchar AS val INNER JOIN eav_attribute AS attr ON attr.attribute_id  = val.attribute_id WHERE attr.attribute_code IN ( 'firstname',  'lastname' )  GROUP BY entity_id ) "); 
        $fcollection = Mage::getModel("franchises/franchisesorder")->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('type' , 1);
        $fcollection->getSelect()->group('main_table.return_transaction_id');
         $fcollection->getSelect() ->joinLeft($customerquery,'main_table.franchises_id = t.entity_id');
        $this->setCollection($fcollection);
        return parent::_prepareCollection();
    }
    protected function _prepareColumns()
    {
                $store = Mage::app()->getStore();
                $this->addColumn("return_transaction_id", array(
                "header" => Mage::helper("franchises")->__("Transaction #"),
                "align" =>"right",
                "width" => "50px",
                "type" => "text",
                "index" => "return_transaction_id",
                ));
```

Change your appropriate value and collection...
only Return collection fields are display in grid column which you want to display other wise use renderer...